# Shown if a set is subspace vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

> Show if $W = \{ (x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})\in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid x_{1}+x_{2}+...+x_{n-1}-x_{n}=0\} $ is a subspace vector.

I have a doubt in the last term ($-x_{n}$) because I tried to take it as if it were a sum like this:
$$ W = \{ (x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})\in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=0$$
After that just prove if the subset:

1. Has vector $0$

$$\displaystyle (0,0,\dots,0) \in W \implies\sum^{n}_{i=1} 0 =0 $$
so $ \quad W \neq 0$.

2. Is closed under addition.

Take any $(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})$ and $(y_{1},\dots,y_{n})$, so
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}= 0 \quad \text{and}\quad \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}= 0 $$
so the linear combination is $0$

3. Is closed under scalar multiplication.

Take any $(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})\in W$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, so
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}= 0 $$
then
$$ \lambda (x_{1},\dots,x_{n})=(\lambda x_{1},\dots,\lambda x_{n}) \in W$$
therefore
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda x_{i}= \lambda \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} = \lambda \cdot 0=0$$
but in all three cases I don't know how to include the last term in my exercise

Comment: You can prove it more generally for the condition $\sum_ia_ix_i=0$ with fixed coefficients $a_i\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: It is a subspace, and given what you’ve put into your question, I believe you are able to prove it for yourself. I think the hold-up might be just how the condition $x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_{n-1} - x_1 = 0$ is presented. Try the proof again, instead rewriting the condition as $x_n =\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x_k$. Do you think you could prove $W$ is a subspace using this form of the condition?

Comment: @TheoBendit You're right, I didn't know how to express it but just add all but the last term of the sum with $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}$, right?

Comment: @MiguelJV Yes, that’s right. Add all the $x_i$ terms from $i=1$ to $i=n-1$. That’s all but the final term: $x_n$.